# issue with client certificate generation for minikube

Tags: minikube, pkcs#12

Facing issue with creating a client certificate for minikube to use with jenkins k8s cd

commands used as follow :

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out ~/.minikube/minikube.pfx -inkey ~/.minikube/apiserver.key -in ~/.minikube/apiserver.crt -certfile ~/.minikube/ca.crt -passout pass:secret
```

The validation failed with error for command:

```
$curl --cacert /root/.minikube/ca.crt --cert /root/.minikube/minikube.pfx:secret --cert-type P12 https://$(minikube ip):8443

curl: (35) error reading X.509 potentially-encrypted key file: Base64 decoding error.
```

Any inputs on this will be very useful

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are creating certificate in wrong way, by exporting existing client apiserver certificate.

In order to create new client certificate (for jenkins) you have to create private key, CSR and signed it using `Cluster Certificate Authority` (CA).

Whole procedure to configure `RBAC` in Kubernetes Cluster can be found [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/).

You should focus on **Step 2: Create The User Credentials** which will allow you to login to cluster but will not authorize new client to do any operations on cluster. If you want to configure authorization you also have to execute **Step 3: Create The Role For Managing Deployments.**

Hope it will help you.